# values on handleSubmit() shows undefined in console log

Tags: reactjs, undefined

The same code worked well in the Previous machine.

Now for some reason, the values in console (in handleSubmit()) shows undefined for email, fullName, and password and then it reaches catch block saying something went wrong! Help.
I have a Signup form:

```
export default function MerchantCreateAccountForm() {
```

Constants such as email, password and name are defined in it:

```
 // set error messages to display to the user
  const [nameError, setNameError] = useState(null);
  const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState(null);
  const [passwordError, setPasswordError] = useState(null);

  // set initial state value(s)
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const authContext = useContext(AuthContext);
```

Mainly, **NEED HELP HERE FOR undefined VALUES FOR email, fullName AND password in handleSubmit()**
Later it reaches to catch block(something went wrong) but that can be another issue.

Here's the function:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {

    try {
      e.preventDefault();
console.log("email is: " +email); //showing undefined in console. HELP
console.log("name is: "+fullName); //showing undefined in console. HELP
console.log("password is: "+password); //showing undefined in console. HELP
      const merchantSignupData =
      {
        data:
        {
          name: fullName,
          email: email,
          password: password,
          client_id: 'testclient',
          client_secret: 'testpass'
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'merchant-signup',
        success: authContext.merchantSignupSuccess,
        error: authContext.networkError
      };
      merchantSignupObject.fullName, merchantSignupObject.password);
      authContext.merchantSignup(merchantSignupData);
    }
    catch{
      console.log("something went wrong!");
      //need to add error handling here
    }

  }
```

I have used validations here although, that works fine, just in case if this might be hampering of setting up the data:

```
  // for every change in our state this will be fired
  // we add validation here and disable the save button if required
  useEffect(() => {

    // we want to skip validation on first render
    if (firstRender.current) {
      firstRender.current = false
      return
    }

    // here we can disable/enable the save button by wrapping the setState function
    // in a call to the validation function which returns true/false
    //setDisabled(formValidation())
    formValidation();
  }, [fullName, password]) // any state variable(s) included in here will trigger the effect to run

  // here we run any validation, returning true/false
  const formValidation = () => {
    let newErrors = {}
    var error = false;

    if (fullName === "") {
      newErrors.fullName = 'Name cant be blank!'
    }
    if (email === "") {
      newErrors.email = 'Email cant be blank!'
    }
    if (!(/.+@.+\.[A-Za-z]+$/.test(email))) {
      newErrors.email = 'Enter a valid email id';
    }
    if (!(/(?=.{7,255}$)(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)/.test(password))) {
      newErrors.password = 'Invalid Password Format';
    }

    setNameError(errors.name)
    setEmailError(errors.email)
    setPasswordError(errors.password)
    

    if (errors != null) {
      //alert("reached")
      setErrors(newErrors);
      // $("#signup-submit").addremoveAttr("disabled") 
    }

    else {
      alert("reached here")
      setNameError(errors.fullName)
      setEmailError(errors.email)
      setPasswordError(errors.password)
      //  $("#signup-submit").removeAttr("disabled") 
    }
  }

  const showError = () => {
    alert('error!');
  }
```

And here's my main form:

```
 return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit()}>

      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <div className="signup">
            <h3>{lang.merchant_signup_create_account}</h3>
            <p>{lang.merchant_signup_account_already}<a href="/linktologinpagecomponentlatertodo">{lang.merchant_signup_sign_in}</a></p>
            <div className="form-group has-error">
              <input type="text" required="required" name="fullName"
                value={fullName}
                placeholder={lang.merchant_signup_name_placeholder}
                onChange={e => setFullName(e.target.value)} />
              <label htmlFor="input" className="control-label">{lang.merchant_signup_name}</label>
              <i className="bar"></i>
              <div className="error">
                <div className="error-msg" role="alert">
                  {errors.fullName && <p>{errors.fullName}</p>}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input type="text" required="required"
                placeholder={lang.merchant_signup_email_placeholder} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
              <label htmlFor="E-mail" className="control-label">{lang.merchant_signup_email}</label><i className="bar"></i>
              <div className="error">
                <div className="error-msg" role="alert">
                  {errors.email && <p>{errors.email}</p>}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input type="password" required="required" placeholder={lang.merchant_signup_password_placeholder} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
              <label htmlFor="Password" className="control-label">{lang.merchant_signup_password}</label><i className="bar"></i>
              <div className="error">
                <div className="error-msg" role="alert">
                  {errors.password && <p>{errors.password}</p>}
                </div>
              </div>
              <ul className="p-suggest">
                <li> {lang.merchant_signup_password_validation1}</li>
                <li>{lang.merchant_signup_password_validation2}</li>
              </ul>
              <ul className="p-suggest">
                <li>{lang.merchant_signup_password_validation3}</li>
                <li>{lang.merchant_signup_password_validation4}</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <p>{lang.merchant_signup_create_terms_warning}<a target="_blank" href="#">{lang.merchant_terms_condition}</a>.</p>
          </div>
          <ul className="list-inline">
            {/* onClick={() => handleSubmit()} */},
              <li><button type="submit" id="signup-submit" className="btn btn-danger create-account next-step">{lang.merchant_signup_create_account_btn}</button></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <img className="img-responsive" src={storeImg} />
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  )
}
```

Comment: There's a bracket mismatch in your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can read see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html),

*Make sure you aren’t calling the function when you pass it to the component:*

So, change your form `onSubmit` method invocation to

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

or

```
<form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit()}>
```

Comment: onSubmit, handleSubmit() method is being called! that's not an issue. That's why reaching to console log of the method. The changes above still shows undefined values.

Comment: @sakshinarang you should not call the method directly. this `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit()}>` is wrong.

Comment: then, if inputs are updated with typed values, i cannot understand what is wrong. we need a fiddle to test it. i cannot think of sth else.

Comment: Yeah, it was working in previous machine, should have worked. not sure why it isn't. The code looks correct( except what you highlighted, though it was still going in that function) Still aint working.

Answer (score 0):

Back to basics, Silly solution:
The attribute value is missing in each input and it was henceforth taking value to be undefined like following:

```
 <input value={password} type="password" required="required" placeholder={lang.merchant_signup_password_placeholder} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
```

Comment: yes but `fullName` had already the value property defined and it was the first thing i checked (i didnt check the others though, since you said that all of them were undefined).

Comment: agreed! your solution resolved half of the problem (main problem)